# Why compilation error: "illegal start of type public static double"?

Tags: java, compiler-errors

Why is this code wrong? btw i'm kinda new

```
import java.util.*;

public class exercicio6_5 {
    public static Scanner sc= new Scanner (System.in);

    public static void main (String args[]) {
        double a[]=new double [sc.nextInt()];
        double val;
        int i=0;
        do
        {
            System.out.println("Valor real: ");
            val=sc.nextDouble();
            a[i]=val;
            i++;
        }
            while (i<a.length);
            System.out.println("A media é: " + media(a,i));


        }
        public static double media(int [a], int i)
        {
            int soma=0;
            int x=0;
            double med;
            do
            {
                soma=soma+a[x];
                x++;
            }
            while (x<i);
            med=soma/i;
            return media;
        }


}
```

The compiler error is "illegal start of type public static double" why ?

Comment: You should at least provide some more information on what is expected and that the actual output is.

Comment: `... media(int [a], ..)` is not correct. Check [Passing Information to a Method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/arguments.html).

Comment: i'm just asking why is there a mistake if i compile

Comment: Asking "why isn't this working" without giving expected behavior and actual behavior/errors is just going to get your question closed. How would you expect anybody to be able to help you without knowing what you expect the code to do? Please read this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: thanks you, what a stupid mistake, it should be ...media(int []a,...)

Comment: If there is a compile error then you should have included the compile error in the question...

Comment: You cant have a method return itself. That's part of the reason why there is a mistake when you compile.

Comment: Now remember that `int[]` doesn't expect `double[]`.

Answer (score 2):

You have the method
`public static double media(int [a], int i)`, this should be `public static double media(double[] a, int i)` since you are inputting a double array not an int array.

Also `int soma = 0` needs to be `double soma = 0` because you aren't trying to add integer values, rather you are trying to add double values.

Also, `return media` should be `return med`, since that is the variable you created.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static double media(int [a], int i)
```

this should be

```
public static double media(int[] a, int i)
```

Comment: Not a complete answer... try and compile yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for the answers, the program is running fine now.
I changed some things in the end that's why it was a bit messy with med/media and int/double but the main problem was putting media(int a[],...), thank you again for the fast answers.